# java concatenate two strings error

Tags: java

I have one function that returns me String :

```
public String getString(String password){

          ......

    try {
    .......
        encodedPassword =  Base64.encodeToString(msgDigest,1 );

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return encodedPassword;

    }
```

I want to add (concatenate) "=" String to returning string from function

I try using this:

```
encrptdPassword = getString("1234");
encrptdPassword = encrptdPassword+"=";
```

Or:

```
encrptdPassword = encrptdPassword .concat("=");
```

but I get result like two different objects (space or brake between)

I think problem is in Base64.encodeToString , but I must use 64 based string

---

Function `getString` returns me:

```
A6xnQhbz4Vx2HuGl4lXwZ5U2I8iziLRFnhP5eNfIRvQ
```

I want to add `=` to the returning string as:

```
A6xnQhbz4Vx2HuGl4lXwZ5U2I8iziLRFnhP5eNfIRvQ=
```

but I receive this on output

```
A6xnQhbz4Vx2HuGl4lXwZ5U2I8iziLRFnhP5eNfIRvQ =
```

Or:

```
A6xnQhbz4Vx2HuGl4lXwZ5U2I8iziLRFnhP5eNfIRvQ
=
```

...like 2 different strings.

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Please post an example of your input and of the wrong result that you are getting. Otherwise it is not clear what is the problem

Comment: I don't understand. Please paste *exactly* what output you're getting and *exactly* what output you're expecting.

Comment: Is this Android? You'd get a lot better answers if you pointed that out or what library you're using for the Base64 class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't the 1 in Base64.encodeToString(msgDigest,1 ) padding?

If it's not, then you could just trim() the string to remove the whitespace.

Comment: @Jovan, maybe trim worked, but I wouldn't rely on it. If the space or carriage return were there before the concatenation, I'd want to understand why. What implementation of base64 are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Base64 from Apache Commons Codec.

The default constructor for this class uses "\r\n" as a line separator, which it adds to the end of every encoded line. If you don't want this, construct the object as:

```
new Base64(76, '');
```

If this isn't the class you're calling (it looks like from your code sample you're calling a static method), check the API and see if you can set a line separator for the conversion.

Comment: can you please post me code ? msgDigest is byte array (byte[])